# Parse JSON from webhook request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webhooks

Using `https://requestb.in`, I can see the webhook is correctly sending the header + json body data. But when I send the json request to my server, I get an error parsing the json.

**My Controller (can't receive body data):**

```
class ReceiverController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

    def handle_post
        puts request.headers['Content-Type']
        puts "request:"
        puts JSON.parse(request.raw_post)
        puts "request2:"
        puts JSON.parse(request.body.read)
    end
end
```

**Error Output:**

```
application/json; charset=utf-8
request:
JSON::ParserError (A JSON text must at least contain two octets!):
app/controllers/receiver_controller.rb:69:in `handle_post'
request2:
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Routes.rb

```
  post "/receive"  => 'receiver#handle_post'
```

Comment: that the ouptput of `puts request.body.read`?

Comment: @Зелёный sorry that was the output of `JSON.parse(request.raw_post)`. I added the output of `JSON.parse(request.body.read)`

Comment: Did you read my comment? Show the output of `puts request.body.read`.

Comment: @Зелёный the output of `puts request.body.read` is blank. I believe something is blocking my server from receiving the json body.

Comment: What is the output of `puts request.raw_post`? If its an **empty string**,then that is the reason for the error.

Comment: I think this question needs some more info to help answer it by providing an MCV example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

1) Could you add an example of how you're making the request?
2) What does ApplicationController look like?
3) Which version of Rails are you using (it looks like it might be an older version)?

Comment: @pavan it is indeed an empty string, the question is why is it empty? Based on the stripe docs it should not be empty with this setup.

Comment: @luissimo Is it related to stripe? I don't see anywhere in the OP about stripe.

Comment: @pavan oh you are right this might not be related to stripe. This is a common error in Stripe though, thats why i thought that.

Comment: Could you post the output of just `request`?

Comment: your request is returning nil, you should check your request not your JSON parse

Comment: As many comments pointed out, the request was not getting through. Turns out, the receiver url (hosted on heroku) needed to be https (secure), or the request would be denied. Others having similar issues should double check their routes/urls if the request is returning nil.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution @Taylor. It would however be good if you could find the time to write an answer with the solution (and accept it) instead of having the solution hidden inside the comments (which are only visible after clicking to expand.

Comment: @loop you asked this question 5 years ago :) , did you already have this problem, or did you wait for it?!

Answer (score 0):

I think rails blocks receiving the request because of **CSRF-protection** that rails provides, I'm a beginner with using **stripe webhooks** but their documentation for webhooks advised me to do the following (https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks):

> If you're using Rails, Django, or another web framework, your site may automatically check that every POST request contains a CSRF token. This is an important security feature that helps protect you and your users from cross-site request forgery attempts. However, this security measure may also prevent your site from processing legitimate webhooks. If so, you may need to exempt the webhooks route from CSRF protection.

```
class ReceiverController < ApplicationController
 # If your controller accepts requests other than webhooks,
 # you'll probably want to use `protect_from_forgery` to add CSRF
 # protection for your application. But don't forget to exempt
 # your webhook route!
 protect_from_forgery :except => :handle_post

 def handle_post
  # Process webhook data in `params`
 end
end
```

Comment: I have the same problem as OP and i have that protect_from_forgery line in my controller, so i think the solutions has to be found somewhere else.

Comment: @luissimo As you mentioned, this didn't solve the problem. I'm using both `protect_from_forgery :except => :handle_post` and `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:handle_post]`